# Android Kotlin regex to replace a substring, get the substring that was replaced

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

If I have a string, say,

```
"Hello, world!"
```

and a regex equation that is

```
"world".toRegex()
```

and I call

```
"Hello, world!".replace("world".toRegex(), "universe")
```

I get the resulting string

```
"Hello, universe!"
```

This is all working as expected... but what if I wanted to keep a copy of that string I took out? I want to keep a copy of "world" in a variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use a callback to `String#replace()` method and assign a variable inside it:

```
var needle = ""
val result = "Hello, world!".replace("world".toRegex()) { needle = it.value; "universe" }
println("Replacement result: " + result)
println("Found match: " + needle)
```

Result:

```
Replacement result: Hello, universe!
Found match: world
```

See the [online Kotlin demo](http://rextester.com/AOXB19894).

You may use a `MutableList<String>` to hold a list of matches and add the matches found to it:

```
var needle = mutableListOf<String>()
val result = "Hello, world! This world is too small.".replace("world".toRegex()) { needle.add(it.value); "universe" }
```

Result:

```
Replacement result: Hello, universe! This universe is too small.
Found match: [world, world]
```

See [another Kotlin demo](http://rextester.com/KSP13153).

Comment: I like your solution. Anyhow it didn't helped me to use regex `(\d{1,4})(\d{1,6})?(\d{1,5})?` to replace `343434343434343` string to `3434-343434-34343`. Any ideas on it?

Comment: @JimitPatel That is something different. Try https://rextester.com/IOLL50071. I do not know why you match the last two groups optionally, though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew cool your solution worked. Just instead of `replace`, I am using `replaceFirst` and optional group is because size is variable of the string, it is basically card number

Answer (score -1):

```
val str = "Hello, world!"
val regex = "world".toRegex()
val matchResult = regex.find(str)
val match = matchResult?.value.orEmpty()
val replaced = str.replace(regex,"universe")
```

Comment: what's wrong with this answer? just that it is not in one line?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I can speculate a bit: (1) this code does two passes on the input, and (2) generally code-only answers are frowned upon. Even if the code seems totally obvious to you, a bit of exposition and explanation or a link to the docs goes a long way to making an answer high-quality. Also, (3) sometimes downvotes happen for arbitrary reasons that you needn't worry about.